# MvxDialogFragment does not show under Android 5 Lollipop

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, android-5.0-lollipop, android-dialogfragment

In our mvvm-application we are using mvxdialogfragments. Everything works fine under android 4.4, but the exact same code does not work with version 5 lollipop. There are no errors, no exceptions etc. they just don't show up :(

The Dialog is launched from a fragment with those lines:

```
          var myDialog = new CalendarPickerView(){ViewModel = new CalendarPickerViewModel(){CurrentMonth = ViewModel.Day}};
          myDialog.Show(Activity.SupportFragmentManager, "Date Selector");
```

and this happens in the dialogs create-method:

```
public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedState)
{
        _singleLock = true;
        ViewModel = MyViewModel;
        EnsureBindingContextSet(savedState);

        View view = this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.CalendarPickerView, null);

        var myDialog = new Dialog(Activity, Resource.Style.CustomDialog);
        myDialog.SetContentView(view);

        MyViewModel.CurrentDate = DateTime.Now.Date;

        var leftButton = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.btn_left);
        leftButton.Click += (sender, args) => MyViewModel.MonthBack();
        var rightButton = view.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.btn_right);
        rightButton.Click += (sender, args) => MyViewModel.MonthForward();

        cal = view.FindViewById<GridView>(Resource.Id.calendarGrid);
        adapt = new CalendarAdapter(Activity);

        cal.ItemClick += cal_ItemClick;
        adapt.ViewModel = MyViewModel;
        MyViewModel.PropertyChanged += MyViewModel_PropertyChanged;
        cal.Adapter = adapt;

        var saveBtn = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.area_Save);
        saveBtn.Click += ((s, a) =>
        {
            _singleLock = false;
            Activity.RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Sensor;
            Dismiss();
        });

        var abortBtn = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.area_Cancel);
        abortBtn.Click += ((s, a) =>
        {
            _singleLock = false;
            Activity.RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Sensor;
            Dismiss();
        });

        myDialog.SetCancelable(false);
        myDialog.SetCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);

        return myDialog;
    }
```

If i use DialogFragment instead of MvxDialogFragment as baseclass for CalendarPickerView and remove all mvvm-related code in the create-method, everything works...

Strangely when debugging CalendarPickerView, the fragment ist listed under FragmentManager.Fragments but Dialog.IsShowing is false. 
mvvm and xamarin are both the latest stable version by 28.11.2014. Did anybody else encounter this problem or do you have any idea what we could do?

thanks in advance!

Comment: "If i use DialogFragment instead of MvxDialogFragment" - is this the same Fragment baseclass? Or is it switching the FullFragging/Fragging(Android Support) one?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem and for me, the problem was not using MvvmCross or MvxDialogFragment. In my original and also in a separate test project I discovered the following reason for the problem:

It seems that - and I know that it sounds ridiculous - overriding the OnStart () method of DialogFragment even with a body that just includes the base.OnStart () call will prevent the dialog from appearing. Have a look at whether you're using OnStart () in your DialogFragment or somewhere in the inheritance hierarchy.

BTW, I suppose this is not necessarily related to Android 5 / Lollipop but that it is related to the ART runtime. I'll try to confirm this once I get to play with Android 5 device that does not make use of the ART runtime.

I've uploaded the sample project here which can be used to reproduce the issue:

https://github.com/nextmunich/XamarinDialogFragmentTest

Comment: Please file a bug with Xamarin at bugzilla.xamarin.com

Comment: Done, you can follow the Bug from here: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=25368